# Call a function from within another function in Python

Tags: python, function

I'm starting to learn Python, but I'm having an issue with my code and was hoping someone could help. I have two functions, and I would like to call one function from the other. When I simply tried calling the function, it seemed to be ignored so I'm guessing it's an issue with how I have called it. Below is the snippet of my code in question.

```
# Define the raw message function
def raw(msg):
    s.send(msg+'\r\n')

    # This is the part where I try to call the output function, but it
    # does not seem to work.
    output('msg', '[==>] '+msg)

    return

# Define the output and error function
def output(type, msg):
    if ((type == 'msg') & (debug == 1)) | (type != msg):
        print('['+strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())+'] ['+type.upper()+'] '+msg)
    if type.lower() == 'fatal':
        sys.exit()
    return

# I will still need to call the output() function from outside a
# function as well. When I specified a static method for output(),
# calling output() outside a function (like below) didn't seem to work.
output('notice', 'Script started')

raw("NICK :PythonBot")
```

Edited. I am actually calling the raw() function, it was just below the snippet. :)

Comment: Are you sure you meant to use `&` and `|` there?

Comment: "When I specified a static method for output()" ... Wait, what?

Comment: You're not calling the first function at all....

Comment: I'm grasping at straws here, but might it be the case that raw and output are names already used in Python? Try renaming the functions, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: You should post an example that is expected to work as is. This snippet is apparently cut out of some bigger code. The problems are probably caused by the code that is not presented here. Try simpler case with *two functions* to make sure that it works.

Comment: Hi. I had simplified the snippet above and it appears it was an issue with a mistake in my code where I was calling it (I had simplified the call to the raw function). Therefore, my assumption of there being a special way of calling a function from within another was incorrect. Thanks to anyone who answered or offered a suggestion. :)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I had previously tried applying StaticMethod to the output() function (I know, I was desperate XD)

Comment: @ColinDunklau Sorry, I left that bit out. I edited a simplified version in just to show that I called it :)

Comment: @jmite Just tried it, it doesn't look like raw() or output() are defined in Python, but thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: @pepr Thanks, I'll definitely bare this in mind in future if I have difficulty with Python :)

Comment: what's the question here? The code seems correct, and you have given no details about input or failure mode. voting to lose.

Comment: I'd be careful using **type** as a variable.  It's a builtin function.  You can override it, but may want to be careful not to do so.

Comment: @Marcin Have you read the other comments on this question? Also, by "failure mode" I assume you are referring to the specific error message, which was briefly explained in the question: "When I simply tried calling the function, it seemed to be ignored". There was no error message; it was simply being ignored. The question has therefore already been provided with the error, and it has already been established that the cause of the issue is due to the way the code is being called and functions can be called within another function normally without any special attributes. :)

Comment: @Dead-i "When I simply tried calling the function, it seemed to be ignored" is not a sufficient description of anything. You should give code, input, and output demonstrating that. The reader should not have to follow the chain of comments to understand the question. Note that even the accepted answer tells you that the question is inadequate.

Comment: @Marcin How would you best describe an error message? I did provide a code snippet above which I believed was the code that was causing the issue. In hindsight I should have tried with a simpler bit of code and displayed that, as other people have suggested.

Comment: @Dead-i First of all, if there is an error message, it should be given in full. Secondly, I have already told you that should show the code *with input and output demonstrating the mode of failure*. Read this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Marcin There was no error message. Also, sscce.org will not resolve for me at this time.

Comment: @Dead-i See http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CE8QIDAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebcache.googleusercontent.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dcache%3A2-nmRZRW48EJ%3Asscce.org%2F%2B%26cd%3D10%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk%26gl%3Dus&ei=37gUUJ79KuqS6gHEq4H4Cg&usg=AFQjCNE4MA71VYhAb3TaFFpjWe-qThpFCA

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try simpler case like this:

```
def func2(msg):
    return 'result of func2("' + func1(msg) + '")'

def func1(msg):
    return 'result of func1("' + msg + '")'

print func1('test')
print func2('test')
```

It prints:

```
result of func1("test")
result of func2("result of func1("test")")
```

Notice the order of function definitions is intentionally reversed. The order of function definitions does not matter in Python.

You should specify better, what does not work for you.

Comment: Thanks for providing an example :)

Comment: Check your original code. As Ignacio mentioned, the `&` and `|` means something else than you expect. Python uses `and` and `or` for boolean expressions.